# How can I end the SSEClient without an event occurring?

Tags: python, multithreading

I've been using this [SSEClient](https://pypi.org/project/sseclient/) Python library with the following code:

```
client = SSEClient(url)
    for event in client:
        func(json.loads(str(event)))
```

This is being run inside a thread. My problem is that I want to end this thread, but when I was attempting to use stop flags, it would only run when an event had been received (as I assume the iterator is waiting on the next item).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to end this thread without another event having to occur?

Thank you!

Comment: Why exactly do you want to end the thread? Can you use daemon thread, so that it ends, when the whole process terminates?

Comment: I was considering that as a last resort, thank you. I just wanted a function that could stop the listening for the sever-sent events, but I'm not sure it's possible from what I've tried.

Comment: I don't see any other way, if the SSEClient is blocked waiting, sorry.

Comment: No worries, thanks for confirming I wasn't missing something!